# Auto resize background image in iOS

Tags: ios, image, swift, background, uikit

I'm having troubles for a while now while exploring Swift to develop an easy iOS app. I followed some tutorials and I'm now trying to build a basic app with a few forms. I'm trying to add a background to my app, but I'm having some troubles with responsibility for my background.

I am new to Swift and developing an iOS-app, I searched on the internet and on SOF, but nobody had a similar problem like this before.

I'm trying to use a 1600 × 1200 background image. I'd like to have it auto-resized by iOS like I do it in my Android app (I put an image as a background image and it's auto resized when in landscape mode or on tablets). Unfortunately, it looks like this is impossible in iOS? Is there someone who can explain me how to get this work for me?

Thanks in advance!

Screenshot: http://gyazo.com/bbea78efa70d744ecca5a00fb325d27e

It's only showing a part from my image, but I want it completely resized for each resolution. It might look too compressed, but it's just an app to experiment with.

Comment: Set the View Mode to "Scale To Fill" in the Attributes Inspector for the UIImageView.

Comment: I tried that before, but for a strange reason, nothing happens. It's still showing a part of the whole background image. (Result on http://gyazo.com/3c16fb31780cf601d77149bd833b165d )

Comment: Your alignment rectangle has large negative numbers.  That looks out of whack.  Try deleting the image view and adding it again.  Drag it's edges to the edges of your view, then "Add Missing Constraints" in Auto Layout by clicking on "Resolve AutoLayout Issues Button" |-^-|.  Don't forget to set "Scale to Fill" again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. This is working for me, but it's not the expected result and I don't know why.

http://gyazo.com/0c24b086c01ac15dc400926bb5908659

Why is it only showing 1/4 of the image instead of being compressed horizontal?

Comment: It still seems like you are missing the Horizontal Constraints.  Get rid of the leading and trailing alignment constraints, then "Add Missing Constraints".  In my case, I have the leading edge of my image aligned to the leading edge of the superview, and the trailing edge of my image aligned to the trailing edge of my superview.